# How to solve the 'undefined reference to libusb' error in ros?

Tags: ros, hardware, camera, makefile, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to transfer a camera(non-uvc) stream program to ros platform.

I've already got the camera driver running

and Makefile is like this:

---

g++ main.cpp -o test_gui -g -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -D_LIN -D_DEBUG -L../lib/x64 -I../include -lASICamera -lpthread -lusb -DGLIBC_20 -m64 -lrt -I/opt

---

Now I want to do this in a ros node, so I write a node in which the CMakelists is like this:

---

include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

include_directories(/root/catkin_ws/src/asi_converter_real/include/asi_converter_real)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

link_libraries(pthread)

link_libraries(usb)

link_libraries(libASICamera.a)

link_libraries(libASICamera.so)

add_executable(asi_converter_real src/asi_converter_real.cpp)

target_link_libraries(asi_converter_real ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

---

And the Makefile line generated into /catkin_ws/build/***/ is like this:

---

/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/asi_converter_real.dir/src/asi_converter_real.cpp.o -o /root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/asi_converter_real/asi_converter_real -rdynamic -L/usr/local/lib -lpthread -lusb -Wl,-Bstatic -lASICamera -Wl,-Bdynamic -lASICamera

---

But it seems that the system cannot find the dynamic libraries of libusb, coz' it reports

---

undefined reference to `libusb_set_configuration'

undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'

/usr/local/lib/libASICamera.a(ASI174MM.o): In function `WorkingFunc(void*)':

undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'

undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'

---

[1]Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem ?

[2]How to find the .a and .so of libusb in my computer ? (I am sure I have them, coz' I can pkg-config --cflags/--libs them)

[3]How could I explicitly link a dynamic library in ros CMakelists ? or just link_libraries(usb) is enough for both static and dynamic libriries ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198217/how-to-solve-the-%27undefined-reference-to-libusb%27-error-in-ros?/) by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't link to both static and dynamic libraries. One or the other is sufficient.

In your case, instead of linking to libASICamera.a and libASICamera.so, you should just do:

```
link_libraries(ASICamera)
```

And cmake will find the appropriate static or dynamic library depending on how you're linking your executable.

Also note that if your libraries have undefined symbols the linking order matters - libraries with undefined symbols should be listed first, and the libraries which contain those symbols should be listed later.

Finally, the `link_libraries()` command is pretty heavy-handed; it will cause all of your executables to be linked against every library you specify. Use `target_link_libraries()` instead, and note that you can list multiple libraries in a single linking command.

Maybe try:

```
target_link_libraries(asi_converter_real ${catkin_LIBRARIES} pthread ASICamera usb)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on 2014-11-25**:
thx very much, it's done.